# How to change generated load on the application dynamically (during execution)?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

For example: Suppose we started a test with 100 vusers load from a machine with certain configuration and realized that the machine is capable of generating another 50 vusers load (assume that application is also scalable).

During the execution whether it is feasible to increase the load to 150 vusers (tool used is Jmeter). Similarly, if the machine is not capable to generate 100 vusers (consuming all the RAM of the machine & CPU utilization is high) whether it is feasible to reduce the load dynamically.

Can this be done through jmeter?
If not, do we have some way to implement the same in jmeter?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312281/change-the-thread-count-of-test-plan-in-jmeter-at-run-time

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Jmeter does not supports increasing / decreasing the thread users (VUsers) while execution. 
In some tools it is allowed. but its not recommended to change the users as it will not create a proper performance report in end.