# Increase number of threads in JMeter during execution

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I have a performance test in `JMeter` and would like to test maximum system performance/throughput with it. So number of active threads should be increased for example while Error rate is under 2 %. I found `Constant Throughput Timer`, put it into `Thread Group` but it only pause or slow down threads. I tried define it as follows, with a property: `${__P(throughput,)}`, but not sure what should be correct value for this property. I can't see how JMeter could measure system maximal performance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the thread count of test plan in JMeter, at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312281/change-the-thread-count-of-test-plan-in-jmeter-at-run-time)

Comment: @user7294900 : There isn't any exact solution on this question.

Comment: Can you share if and how you succeeded to achieve it?

Comment: @user7294900 : Please check accepted answer, it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality in the "vanilla" JMeter howere it is possible with plugins, check out:

- [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/)

They can be connected together via [feedback loop](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Schedule-Feedback-Function) so Concurrency Thread Group will add more threads if needed to reach the desired number of requests per second.

You can install both the plugins (and keep them up-to-date) using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: Thanks! How is it possible to connect these with error rate? So how could I increase number of threads since error rate is below a predefined value?

Comment: Not sure regarding stopping increasing load, however you can stop the whole test if errors rate exceeds certain threshold via [AutoStop Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-autostop-listener-how-to-do-it-right)

Answer (score 4):

There is no Out of the box solution as of JMeter 3.3, see this enhancement request:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57640

Still it is possible to dynamically add threads since JMeter 3.2 (see https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60530) in a JSR223 Test Element using [JMeterContext](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html):

> ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(delay, ctx.getEngine());

So based on this, you could in a JSR223 Test Element (Pre/Post Processor or Sampler) check the presence of a file in a folder of your choice named :

> NUMBER_OF_THREAD_TO_ADD.txt

If present, use its name to compute number of threads and call this method.

Comment: Where should I see this folder please?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can select whatever folder you want since it will be your code that will use this folder