# JMeter - reduce threads on runtime

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Sometimes we execute JMeter script on production and it causes a load on servers

I don't want to stop the test, only reduce the load on server

How can I reduce threads number on runtime to avoid performance issues on server on load?

I saw [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312281/change-the-thread-count-of-test-plan-in-jmeter-at-run-time) asked in the past with answers that say it cannot be done

> The short answer is: no, you cannot change the number of threads dynamically during runtime. Each thread count value is only read once when the test plan is first compiled and is not resolved again after this point, so it remains fixed.

If it can't be done, can/should I add timers that can add pauses on runtime?

**EDIT** I saw there's an open [enhancement](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57640): Add ability to modify load while a test is running

I saw [blazemeter blog post](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime) about using Beanshell server, but it seems an overhead for such rare cases

> able to change the load generated by the performance test, without stopping the test. This can be done by using Apache JMeter™´s Constant Throughput Timer and the Beanshell server

Answer (score 0):

Reducing number of threads currently can be implemented in 2 ways:

1. Putting thread to "sleep" without actually stopping it, can be achieved using [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) Sampler

   [image]
2. The same test element but for stopping the thread:

   [image]

In order to be able to run the sampler conditionally you can put it under the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) providing appropriate entry criteria

If you want to get the thread(s) back it can be done using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) invoking [ThreadGroup.addNewThread() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/ThreadGroup.html#addNewThread-int-org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine-)

```
ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread(0, ctx.getEngine())
```

Comment: But how I should communicate with the running test to enforce the sleep/stop?

Comment: You mentioned the [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server). If it is not suitable for your needs you can also consider [Redis Dataset](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/Using-Redis-Dataset-JMeter-Plugin) or [writing a custom plugin](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) which will be listening for JMXRMI properties changes so you will be able to control the load via [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) or similar software